# XPages XSP Dialog not working

Tags: ajax, xpages, lotus-notes

I have an XPage with several extension library dialogs which up to now had been working fine. Today I noticed that none of the dialogs work and I can't figure out why. I created a test dialog on another, new, XPage and this does work fine. The same test dialog on the original XPage does not work. This problem exists with both IE and Firefox. I'm using Notes and Domino 8.5.3 SP1. Any idea what the problem could be? The code for the test dialog is

```
<xp:panel>
<xp:button value="Dialog Test" id="button1">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
<xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.openDialog("#{id:TestDialog}")]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xe:dialog id="TestDialog">
<xp:label value="TEST" id="label1"></xp:label>
</xe:dialog>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors shown in browser console?

Comment: no, no errors were shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to make a guess based on the limited information here, I'd wager that you possibly lost the definition of your xe workspace on your first XPage. Your xp:view object should look like this:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
</xp:view>
```

Comment: I made some changes to another custom control containing an accordion pane which caused this problem. Not sure exactly what caused the problem but resetting those changes got everything back working as before.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue myself. Eventually I spotted a parameter I didn't recognise in my xpage, namely createForm:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
   xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom" createForm="false">
```

That createForm value was preventing the form for my dialog from being created. Once I removed the createForm value from the xp:view definition, the dialog worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably error in dialog's content. This error is hidden inside partial refresh response, so you have to use web developer tools/firebug to see actual response in network tab. You will probably find error page as a response. In case you don't use try/catch exception handling, you may also find the exception in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT directory inside server's data directory in xpages_exc*.log file.